# How to recreate view in tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabbed-activity

I am changing from blank activity to tabbed activity. I want to recreate view at certain points. I have tried `notifyDataSetChanged`and
`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace (R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(1)).commit();`

But they didn't work.
How can I recreate tab?

Also, one small question, while copy/paste during changing activity I need to copy onStart to onStart of fragment and onStop to onDestroyView. Right?

EDit 1:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e0e0e0"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="lcukerd.com.stocknotifier.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/stock_linear"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/value_linear"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/reqd_value_linear"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/check_linear"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I am populating them with textview dynamically.
I have 3 tabs all have same structure.
I hope this will do.

Comment: Please show a mock up of your desired UI.

Comment: What do you mean by mock up? @Code-Apprentice

Comment: I mean to draw a picture in MS Paint, Photoshop, or some other image editing software and upload it to your question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Have a look.

Comment: That is not a picture.